# How do I reset nbdev_build_docs

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I had an import error that i have long cleared but nbdev_build_docs is stuck on that line. When I search through the project folder the line is not found

The error is:

```
from nbdev.showdoc import show_doc
from pyintegrators.twitter import *
------------------

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f63d9caafaed> in <module>
      1 from nbdev.showdoc import show_doc
----> 2 from pyintegrators.twitter import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyintegrators.twitter'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyintegrators.twitter'
```

Yet when I search the project directory for that error i get No results found
It looks like I am dealing with a cache. How do I make it forget?

I am using macOs